# Add new Echosign template in Salesforce

Tags: configuration

I have been trying to create a EchoSign template in salesforce. I am searching for this for last two days but couldn't find anything working. Here's the thing that I have to do.

Adding the Echosign templates that are available to send. Create a button called “New Agreement” that will create the appropriate agreement and insert the appropriate fields from the Contact, Account, and Month & Date. Here's the thing that I know so far.

- I have to use Merge Mapping to merge field data from salesforce to Echosign Template.
- Data Mapping is used to store EchoSign data back to Salesforce.
- I have to add that Merge Mapping record in Merge Mapping lookup in EchoSign Templates.

The problem is (the one that I am facing right now) that I am adding field (Title) from Contact in Merge Mapping. But that field's value doesn't show up in EchoSign agreement preview. However, when I select Constant as a Source Type in Merge Mapping and add some value, that value is showed in previe. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

i have faced same issue. Follow below points to resolve

1) Give Visible permission to all record types for that field. you should able to see the title in merge mapping.

Please let me know does it resolve your problem.

Thanks,
Veera